# API Authentication, once or every time?

Tags: javascript, api, authorization

I am trying to fetch multiple datapoints from an API and do some calculations based on the data.

So far I have incorporated the username and password inside every fetch statement, and there are quite a few of them:

```
fetch(url, {
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(uname + ':' + pass)
        },
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
```

But I see now that the API supports login, and I am wondering, is it possible to do login once, fetch what I need while logged in and then log out?

This is the relevant options I have:

- GET - DoWebLoginToken
- POST - DoWebLogin
- POST - Logout

If the answer is yes, kindly explain how do I go about logging in through code?

Comment: `the API supports login` - then follow the API's documented method of loging in. It's not like saying "the API supports login" and we'll know exactly which API and how it works

Comment: @JaromandaX What I see in the documentation is what I copied here, it's all I know.

Comment: Searching the internet for `DoWebLoginToken` results in exactly one result - this question - so perhaps if you share a link to the API documentation